# Hibernate can not save object

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am doing the introductory tutorial on Hibernate from PluralSight.
For my database, I am using MYSQL.

In my main method, I am creating an object and I am trying to save it.
However, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.simpleprogrammer.User
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:776)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1447)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:678)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:670)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:665)
    at com.simpleprogrammer.Program.main(Program.java:16)
```

My main method is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        Session session = HibernateUtilities.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        User user = new User();
        user.setName("Joe");
        user.setGoal(250);
        session.save(user);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        HibernateUtilities.getSessionFactory().close();
    }
```

The error appears on the line with `session.save(user);`

My Utilities class:

```
package com.simpleprogrammer;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;


public class HibernateUtilities {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private static StandardServiceRegistryBuilder ssrb;

    static
    {
        try
        {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

            ssrb = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(ssrb.build());
        }
        catch(HibernateException exception)
        {
            System.out.println("Problem creating session factory");
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }


}
```

My `hibernate.cfg.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory name="">
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">appuser</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">appuser</property>
  <property name="hibernate.default_schema">protein_tracker</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
  <mapping resource="com/simpleprogrammer/User.hbm.xml"/>
 </session-factory
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I am sorry to post all this code, but I'm not sure which part is relevant.
I suspect that my error is caused by the database connection, but I'm not sure how to check that.

Comment: Show `User` class and User.hbm.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I had a syntactic error on the line:

```
</session-factory
```

This was in `hibernate.cfg.xml`

Answer (score 0):

This is my first contribution to stackoverflow.com. And I was facing similar error,but now I resolved it by this given solution. So, I am writing this Answer.

You have to change your utility file like this:

```
static
{
    try
    {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

        //ssrb = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
    }
    catch(HibernateException exception)
    {
        System.out.println("Problem creating session factory");
    }
}


public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

1. ssrb variable declaration and definition must be removed.
2. put *configuration.buildSessionFactory();* instead of *configuration.buildSessionFactory(ssrb.build());*